# How can I send html/javascript values to sql and return it back to the same page in jsp?

Tags: java, sql, html, jsp, jdbc

I started out with an html page.  Then, I renamed the file with a .jsp extension, as I will be using jsp to accomplish this particular task.

Which is: I wish to take a value from the page on a form, send it to sql to be used in a where clause, then send the data set back to the same page.  Now, I could likely employ AJAX, instead of submitting a form.  I would appreciate some advice, like a step-by-step procedure, for I'm bewildered about at least a couple of items.  1) Can I write the JSP code in the same page? 2) Can or should I write SQL inside the JSP code?  3) Should I Have another page set up just for JSP?

I suppose I'm looking for a "Hello World" explanation, as I've primarily worked with non-java based languages in the past.

Thank you.

Comment: I would avoid writing SQL in your JSP code. But always always always practice _separation of concerns_, and never repeat the same word three times like I just did :]

Comment: Thank you for that knowledge drop.  I can see JSP is not very similar to ASP or PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For quick and dirty, you should look at using the JSTL SQL tags. They're pretty easy to use, actually, and eliminate much of the JDBC cruft if you simply embedded Java.

[This page](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jstlsql/) is a decent little example that covers most of the fundamentals, for SQL with JSTL.

Answer (score 2):

1) You can write JSP (Java) code in the same file, but it is not recommended.
2) Same as 1. you can write SQL code in JSP, but you shouldnt.
3) HTMLs renamed to JSPs are perfectly valid jsp files.

I suggest that you use a MVC framework like [Spring MVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) to do your task. Here's a [tutorial](http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/).

UPDATE: Standard JSP & servlet tutorials

1. http://archive.coreservlets.com/Chapter3.html
2. http://archive.coreservlets.com/Chapter16.html
3. http://archive.coreservlets.com/Chapter15.html
4. http://archive.coreservlets.com/Chapter3.html

Comment: Thank you.  At the moment, it's just a proof-of-concept page.  So, I was looking for a quicker solution, as I don't pass all the requirements just yet.  Then, I can refactor the code to use the framework.  At least I know what is considered common, correct practice, thanks to you.  But I was hoping for a quick, dirty solution for the moment.  Thank you again.

Comment: Well, dont really have the time to write a Hello World app you need, but i added some more tutorials that are very basic and simple.. Hope that helps.